# Spring Security xsd does not allow realm attribute on http-basic tag

Tags: spring, spring-security

Why is the attribute `realm` missing on  for the `xsd` file, when `AuthenticationConfigBuilder` allow such attribute to be provided ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<http realm="memorynotfound.com">
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
  <http-basic entry-point-ref="basicAuthEntryPoint"/>
  <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

It is on the outer element.